# How to read Http Response

Tags: android, http-post

I am authenticating my users using OAuth 2.0, and I have to make an http post request (sending my client id, client secret etc). I think I am doing that successfully. As a response I am supposed to get the access token and other information. But when I print the response in my LogCat it comes out as "org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@407e7bb0". Where do I find the message? Below is my code and I followed this example http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

```
public class PasteCode extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pastecode);

    final EditText codeinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Button send_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String code = codeinput.getText().toString();

            new Thread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?");

     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "---------"));
     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "---"));
     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg..."));
     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // writing error to Log
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

     // Making HTTP Request

try {
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

     // writing response to log
     Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // writing exception to log
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     // writing exception to log
     e.printStackTrace();

     }

     }
    }).start();

    }
});
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String str = "";

while ((str = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(str);
}

String text = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from nikis should work fine, but I find this [static method found in EntityUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) to be a bit more terse. If you look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java#EntityUtils.toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%2Cjava.nio.charset.Charset%29), you'll see that the implementations are relatively similar.

Comment: Thank you very much both, I got it working using the BufferReader.